# Error with ArcGIS js API Create web map by ID sample

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have been trying to use the updated ArcGIS API for Javascript, with ArcGIS Online.  I have been testing with the sample code found on the "Create web map by ID" page:

http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/ags_createwebmapid.html

If I download that and try to run it in Firefox, without making any changes, then the map does not show up and I get the following error reported in Firebug:

```
Error: Unable to load the base map layer
[Break On This Error]   

...);}},_getKind:function(_2ff){var _300=this._trackManager;if(_300){return _300.is...

utils.js (line 19)
```

The sample runs fine on the http://developers.arcgis.com/ site, I'm not sure why it would be failing for me.  I am not accessing the web through a proxy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find an ArcGIS forum post for a similar issue:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/54811-Proxy-page-error-using-editor-widgit

The directions for creating a proxy page for viewing ArcGIS Online maps can be found here:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jshelp/ags_proxy.html

Answer (score 2):

Works fine after I changed the relative reference to layout.css -- cheers!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/samples/ags_createwebmapid/css/layout.css">
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work.  I'm still getting the same issue on the base map layer.

Comment: Can you get other samples to work on your test platform? Different browsers?

Comment: I also tested in IE and Chrome.   I did try the sample for http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/map_simple.html  and that one is working correctly.  However, it is not using an ArcGIS Online map.

Comment: What about this one where you "Create web map using JSON"? Not using a proxy there either, but it does reference a base map...  http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/ags_createwebmapitem.html

Comment: That one is working also.  I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting the different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to create web maps is to install cartoview www.cartologic.com/cartoview and create a webmap
the steps are available at
http://cartologic.com/cartoview/apps/cartoserver/help/webmap/#settings